# training Parallel models in keras vs sequentially

Tags: python, parallel-processing, keras, gpu

I have the following code which is training the same model with different datasets in parallel. I want to know what is the difference between the result I get in this code vs if I train the model one by one using the corresponding datasets.Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
from keras.layers import *
from keras.models import Model, Sequential
import numpy as np
import random
import test
index=[]
for i in range(10):
    index.append(random.sample(range(0, 201), 10))
x_tr=[]
y_tr=[]
x_te=[]
y_te=[]

aa = test.train_data(index[0])
X_train0, Y_train0, X_Test0, Y_Test0 = test.ddata(aa)
aa = test.train_data(index[1])
X_train1, Y_train1, X_Test1, Y_Test1 = test.ddata(aa)
aa = test.train_data(index[2])
X_train2, Y_train2, X_Test2, Y_Test2 = test.ddata(aa)
aa = test.train_data(index[3])
X_train3, Y_train3, X_Test3, Y_Test3 = test.ddata(aa)
aa = test.train_data(index[4])
X_train4, Y_train4, X_Test4, Y_Test4 = test.ddata(aa)
aa = test.train_data(index[5])
X_train5, Y_train5, X_Test5, Y_Test5 = test.ddata(aa)
aa = test.train_data(index[6])
X_train6, Y_train6, X_Test6,Y_Test6 = test.ddata(aa)
aa = test.train_data(index[7])
X_train7, Y_train7, X_Test7, Y_Test7 = test.ddata(aa)
aa = test.train_data(index[8])
X_train8, Y_train8, X_Test8, Y_Test8 = test.ddata(aa)
aa = test.train_data(index[9])
X_train9, Y_train9, X_Test9, Y_Test9 = test.ddata(aa)


m=test.get_model()
inp0=Input((5,10,10,1))
inp1=Input((5,10,10,1))
inp2=Input((5,10,10,1))
inp3=Input((5,10,10,1))
inp4=Input((5,10,10,1))
inp5=Input((5,10,10,1))
inp6=Input((5,10,10,1))
inp7=Input((5,10,10,1))
inp8=Input((5,10,10,1))
inp9=Input((5,10,10,1))
out0=m(inp0)
out1=m(inp1)
out2=m(inp2)
out3=m(inp3)
out4=m(inp4)
out5=m(inp5)
out6=m(inp6)
out7=m(inp7)
out8=m(inp8)
out9=m(inp9)





model = Model([inp0,inp1,inp2,inp3,inp4,inp5,inp6,inp7,inp8,inp9],[out0,out1,out2,out3,out4,out5,out6,out7,out8,out9])
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
model.fit([X_train0,X_train1,X_train2,X_train3,X_train4,X_train5,X_train6,X_train7,X_train8,X_train9],[Y_train0,Y_train1,Y_train2,Y_train3,Y_train4,Y_train5,Y_train6,Y_train7,Y_train8,Y_train9], epochs = 50)
ypred0,ypred1,ypred2,ypred3,ypred4,ypred5,ypred6,ypred7,ypred8,ypred9 = model.predict([X_Test0,X_Test1,X_Test2,X_Test3,X_Test4,X_Test5,X_Test6,X_Test7,X_Test8,X_Test9])
print(ypred0.shape)
```

FYI-test is another where I get my data from.

Answer (score 1):

It's best to train in parallel or all at once than sequentially.

If you train it sequentially you might end up by overfitting on the last dataset on which you train the model.

Comment: would parallel training still work if I have completely different datasets.e.g image of cat vs apple. The architecture of both models will be same.

Comment: Yes and it would give better results than sequential training